# Save only required data in MongoDB and node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

**I want to store only username in the mentions array pointing to the user from the same collection** but it is saving all data of mentioned user in MongoDB like following:

```
{
    "userId": "62db90256a7a0d1b38ee15b5",
    "media": [
        "nothing"
    ],
    "mentions": [
        {
            "_id": "62db797c0d2bdc605e6d1810",
            "Name": "Mitul Kheni",
            "email": "test@gmail.com",
            "User_name": "Mitul_kheni",
            "phoneNumber": "1234567890",
            "password": "$2a$08$pb6Nu8MlIX7.L0S8vBP6NOFxjc9rZCXOUFA9.IsMBwkENmap946yO",
            "gender": "male",
            "followers": [],
            "following": [],
            "BlockedUser": [],
            "profileStatus": "public",
            "Like": [],
            "disLike": [],
            "tokens": [
                {
                    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MmRiNzk3YzBkMmJkYzYwNWU2ZDE4MTAiLCJpYXQiOjE2NTg1NTA2NTIsImV4cCI6MTY1ODYzNzA1Mn0.128eZ80OjCxMEk3A_mRpInR1ZP4L-YdgTS2JBQUJjxs",
                    "_id": "62db797c0d2bdc605e6d1812"
                }
            ],
        },
```

It is saving all the users that are stored into a database in the mentions array like above even if I haven't mentioned that user.

the query to create a new post:

```
exports.createPost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    if (!user) return res.status(401).json({ message: "No user found" });
    const { media, hashTags, postStatus } = req.body;

    const mentions = await User.find({ User_Name: req.body.User_Name });
    if (!mentions) {
      return res.status(404).send("Please enter valid user name");
    }

    let new_post = new Post({
      userId: req.user._id,
      media,
      mentions,
      hashTags,
      postStatus,
    });
    const post = await new_post.save();
    return res.status(200).send(post);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
};
```

The user_name schema from post table:

```
mentions: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    },
```

How can I restrict this to save only username and only mentioned username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    let new_post = new Post({
      userId: req.user._id,
      media,
      mentions,
      hashTags,
      postStatus,
    });
```

You are directly passing the mentions obtained from mongodb while creating a `Post` object. Instead, you should map it to only save username. Like this:

```
    let new_post = new Post({
      userId: req.user._id,
      media,
      mentions: mentions.map(user => {User_name: user.User_name}),
      hashTags,
      postStatus,
    });
```

Or you can project, only User_name from your query like this:

```
const mentions = await User.find({ User_Name: req.body.User_Name }, {User_name: 1, _id: 0});
```

**UPDATE**

We were searching by wrong key, it should be `User_name`, not `User_Name`, try this:

```
const mentions = await User.find({ User_name: req.body.User_Name }, {User_name: 1, _id: 0});
```

Also check, what is the exact key, present in the request body.
To check for an empty array, apply the following condition:

```
if (req.body.mentions && (!Array.isArray(mentions) || mentions.length === 0)) {
  return res.status(404).send("Please enter valid user name");
}
let postBody = {
  userId: req.user._id,
  media,
  hashTags,
  postStatus,
};
if(mentions.length > 0) {
  postBody = {...postBody, mentions};
}
let new_post = new Post(postBody);
```

Comment: The second solution is saving only username but it is saving all the user's username from database not only that I have mentioned in a request

Comment: It should be ```const mentions = await User.find({ User_name: req.body.mentions }, {User_name: 1, _id: 0});``` It is now saving only mentioned user but if I type wrong username then it is not checking this condition ```if (!mentions) {return res.status(404).send("Please enter valid user name") }``` .It is just saving an empty array

Comment: Updated the answer with a check for mentions. If mentions is not array, or it is an empty array, an error will be thrown.

Comment: I apologize for asking you over and over again but if I check ```mentions.length``` Then user have to provide mention in a post and it is not mandatory. What if someone do not want to tag any one. so I removed that part and I am back at the same problem again. If mention found valid username from User's collection then it is saving only mentioned user but if it doesn't found valid username the post is getting saved as an empty mentions array

Comment: No issues. Apply more conditions according to your use case. I have updated the answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73090267/19532773 Last question only I promise. Please go through the linked question and answer it please.

Comment: No worries added a comment there